# Viewing index data in multiple kibana spaces

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

how to view my index data from one space in different kibana space?
I have created a role and user for the space,
given all the kibana privileges to the role, and now I want to view the data of my existing space in this new space,
but i am unable to do it , not sure how to go ahead.

Comment: you mean dashbord and visulisation ?

Comment: Indexes do not "belong" to a space. In any space you can create roles which can access any indexes. You need to make sure that each role in each space has access to all the data you need and that will work.